# Remove object from jsonb array based on value of object

Tags: postgresql

If I define a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  data JSONB
);
INSERT INTO test (id, data) VALUES (1, '[{"a": "x", "b":"b"}, {"c": "y", "b":"b"}]');
```

How can I remove any object in the array with key "a" that has value "x"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove these JSON objects by running the following update:

```sql
update test set data = new_data.new_data
from (
    select id, json_agg(element) as new_data
    from test,
         jsonb_array_elements(data) as element
    where not element ? 'a' or element ->> 'a' != 'x'
    group by id
) new_data
where new_data.id = test.id
```

The subquery in `new_data` removes the objects that contain a  key `a` with a value of `x` from the `data` `jsonb` array. This is done by first unpacking the JSON array so that we can evaluate a condition on them, then doing the filtering, then creating a new JSON array from the objects that were retained. The filtering `not element ? 'a' or element ->> 'a' != 'x'` consists of two conditions, the first checks if the element doesn't contain an `a` key, while the second one checks if the value of `a` is not `x`. If either evaluates to true, the element is retained.

The result of the subquery is then used to update the original table's `data` column.

You can see the results on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/x41dkQ2J).